# Creating a dialog JQuery Mobile with external page

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I want to create two page, the first contains the button that will display the second, and the second g appears in the form of a dialogue box.

```
data-role= dialog
```

for first page i add this codd to add button

```
$('#header-left-container').prepend(results.rows.item(i).LibelleTypeTravail +"" +
                "<br>" +
                "<a  href='../prestation_html/list_rubrique.html' data-transition='flip' data-rel='dialog'  > <img src='../js/images/add.png' > </a>" +
                "<textarea rows='6'  cols='60'  name='"+results.rows.item(i).LibelleTypeTravail+"'> </textarea><br><br>" );
```

for second page "list_rubrique.html" i add this:

```
<div data-role='page'>

<div data-role="data-role="dialog"  id="popupBasic" data-theme="a" >

<ul>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>
```

but does not work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your *dialog* is nested inside of a *page*, the dialog should exist on its own.

To [display](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/dialog/index.html) a dialog, you have two options either use a regular page and in your link use `data-rel="dialog"`, OR instead of using the `data-role="page"` on your destination page, use instead a `data-role="dialog"`.

For example in your case you should just be able to switch your markup in your `list_rubrique.html` page to

```
<div data-role="data-role="dialog"  id="popupBasic" data-theme="a" >   
  <ul>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
 </ul>   
</div>
```